# What is the purpose of `$_useIsObjectNew`

Tags: magento-core

In magento I autogenerated, with the use of the Magento extension in phpstorm, some models for use.

In those autogenerated models I noticed that in the `__construct()` methods `$this->$_useIsObjectNew` is used and set to true.

Curious to its use I decided to check the description for this flag. [$_useIsObjectNew](https://github.com/pepe1518/magento2/blob/master/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php#L83)

```php
    /**
     * Use is object new method for save of object
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_useIsObjectNew = false;
```

> Use is object new method for save of object

This didn't enlighten me much more, it feels like a riddle posted by a sphinx, so hence my question:

What is the purpose of this flag, and why would you want to set it to either true or false?

Comment: Your answer is there > https://github.com/pepe1518/magento2/blob/master/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php#L743

Comment: @SohelRana Yes, but still doesn't explain the logic of the choice of the parameter, and **why** you would use it. I'm more interested in the resons for using it with set to true or set to false. Why would one use this variable?

Comment: This is legacy M1 implementation.

Comment: @SohelRana Your comments still don't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

The flag is use for the following things.

1. It will check, if the Object created newly, then add the data into this one. (Add data operation)
2. If this not new, then data update is perform. (Edit/Update data operation)

Comment: What you describe is the behavior used in https://github.com/pepe1518/magento2/blob/master/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php#L741 which is used here https://github.com/pepe1518/magento2/blob/master/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php#L402 but not the purpose of this flag. Your answer does not explain why you would want this flag to skip the `isObjectNew()` call